# CPU Temperatures

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature

I have an issue with my FX8350 on Gigabyte 990XA-UD3.

I've set a BIOS buzzer warning to sound off when the socket temp exceeds 60C/140F.

On my FX8350 I have an CM Hyper 212 EVO, and the CPU is running at stock temps, without turbo-mode. (8cores @ 4GHz).

I'm also running with Cool n' Quite on, so that should further keep the processor cool, since it underclocks and undervolts the CPU when it's not under load.

I've replaced all of the dust filters on my case, and vacuumed the inside of my computer.

The room temperature is around 28C/82F. (I know it's not ideal).

Now, the problem I'm running into is that the buzzer sounds off (socket temp exceeds 60C/140F) during some operations. Like `#include` parsing in `Visual Studio` or when playing `Dota 2` and in a `Skype` call at the same time. Now I know these are CPU intensive operations (include parsing, and Dota2), but this CPU with aftermarket cooling, both on the CPU and in the case, shouldn't go anywhere near that temperature. What's the problem here? Could it be that Cool n' Quiet is actually doing the opposite of what it's intended to do? Underclocking thus making the CPU run under higher load, and have a higher heat dispersion? The CPU's TDP is 125W, but during the temp spikes it never exceeds ~40W.

Comment: Are you sure the thermal paste is properly applied?

Comment: What are your idle temps?

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton It was, this isn't a new build. It has been working properly for quite some time now.

Comment: @DrZoo ~30C/86F

Comment: Did you just recently set up the BIOS buzzer, or is it something you've implemented a long time ago? I've been looking at some forums/reviews where users have the same cooler and 60C doesn't seem unreasonable. I've seen quite a few reviews where they say they run at 60C when playing games. 60C is also a very normal temp. It's definitely not something that will damage your CPU. Your warmer room temperature could also contribute to the higher temp. Personally, I would set the buzzer for something high like 75-80C. Then it would indicate when there is actually a potential problem.

Comment: @DrZoo I did. But it hasn't been running so hot until now. With aftermarket cooling and stock clocks it really should be under 60C at full load. My best guess would be that the thermal paste started degrading, so I'll replace that and see what happens.